# Get the day of the week code (int) from proper name (string) with Python Standard Library

Tags: python

Is there a **tricky cool** way to get [`calendar.weekday(year, month, day)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday) or [`datetime.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) (or something else in the PSL) to give you the *day of the week code* (`int`) from any of the standard proper names or abbreviations (`str`) for a *day of the week word*?

Or do I have to use this **clunky** dict?

```
>>> day_code = {'MO' : 0, 'TU' : 1, 'WE' : 2, 'TH' : 3, 'FR' : 4, 'SA' : 5, 'SU' : 6,
'MONDAY' : 0, 'TUESDAY' : 1, 'WEDNESDAY' : 2, 'THURSDAY' : 3, 'FRIDAY' : 4, 
'SATURDAY' : 5, 'SUNDAY' : 6, 'M' : 0, 'T' : 1, 'W' : 2, 'T' : 3, 'F' : 4, 'MON' : 0,
'TUE' : 1, 'WED' : 2, 'THU' : 3, 'FRI' : 4, 'SAT' : 5, 'SUN' : 6, 'TUES' : 1, 
'THUR' : 3, 'THURS' : 3}
>>> day_code['mon'.upper()]
0
```

Comment: I don't think so. There are third-party libraries that will parse flexible date formats, but the standard `datetime` library requires you to specify the format of the date that's being parsed.

Comment: BTW, you have a duplicate T key. I think the single letter for Thursday is normally R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of string splitting in this case as follows

```
day_code = {'MO' : 0, 'TU' : 1, 'WE' : 2, 'TH' : 3, 'FR' : 4, 'SA' : 5, 'SU' : 6}
day = 'mon'
print(day_code[day[:2].upper()])
```